# Working with <div> tag in JSP for making the contents hidden or visible

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, html

I have written a javascript function.

```
function wellChecked(state) {
if (state)
{
wellDropDown.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else
{
wellDropDown.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
}
```

I have a checkbox after the `Well Modification <td>` as given below,

```
<tr>
  <td>On Call</td>
  <td><html:checkbox property="onCall"/></td>
  <td>Well Modification</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="wellChecked(this.checked)" /></td>
</tr>
```

When that checkbox is clicked I want the drop down list given under the `div id=wellDropDown` to be displayed. Defaultly, if the check box is not clicked, the drop down should not be displayed.

```
<tr>
  <td>Active</td>
  <td><html:checkbox property="active"/></td>
<div id="wellDropDown" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <td>     
    <html:select property="wellFormatId">
    <html:option value="">(Select)</html:option>
    <bean:define id="wellFormatColl"  name="wellFormats" scope="request"/>
    <logic:iterate id="wellFormats" name="wellFormatColl" indexId="index" type="com.astrazeneca.compis.data.WellFormatVO">
        <% Long wellId = wellFormats.getWellFormatId();%>
        <% String wellIdNo = wellId.toString(); %>
        <html:option value="<%=wellIdNo%>">
        <bean:write name="wellFormats" property="wellFormatName"/>
        </html:option>
    </logic:iterate>
    </html:select>
  </td>
 </div>
</tr>
```

When I tried executing this code, I could see the drop down list getting displayed irrespective of the checkbox checked or not.

Where I have went wrong in this scenario? Please give ur suggestions or ways to implement my requirement.

Comment: wellDropDown - this is used in your js function, but where is it defined?

Comment: I atleast think you need to use `document.getElementById('id-here').style.visibility = 'hidden/visible';` instead of wellDropDown.

Comment: @ManishSharma wellDropDown is the `id` attribute of the `div` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You may not have a `div` enclose a `td` like this. Either make the `td` itself visible or invisible, or put the `div` inside the `td`, instead of putting it around the `td`.

Also, unless `wellDropDown` is a global JS variable, the code should be

```
document.getElementById("wellDropDown").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Answer (score 1):

with jquery you could do this :

```
    <tr>
      <td>On Call</td>
      <td><html:checkbox property="onCall"/></td>
      <td>Well Modification</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" /></td>
    </tr>
...

<script>
$('#myDropDown').click(
  function () {             
    $("#wellDropDown").toggle();    
  });
);
</script>
```